# How do i exclude a record from a result based on a table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result set that looks as follows from the following sp:

```
SELECT g2.ID, g2.[Name]
    FROM cte c
        LEFT JOIN #Market gc WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.ID = gc.ID
        INNER JOIN list.Type gt WITH(NOLOCK) ON g2.TypeId = gt.TypeID
    WHERE  
        gt.MarketCount IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY g2.GameID, g2.[Name] 
ORDER BY g2.[Name]
```

this is the output

```
 ID     | Name
    2   |Apple
    5   |Pear
    14  |Strawberry
```

Now i have  an other  table called mapping as follows

```
ID  | Name
14  | Strawberry
```

what i am trying to achieve is that from the above data result that i got back from the stored procedure i want to compare it onto the mappings table, if theirs an ID in Mapping that matches the result set it should ignore that row and give me the following results,example:Expected outcome

```
        ID  | Name
        2   |Apple
        5   |Pear
```

Because ID 14 was present in the mapping table that record should have been removed

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start. Also...https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those columns who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

use left join and filter by where mapping table is not mapped

```
with t1 as
     (SELECT g2.ID, g2.[Name]
            FROM cte c
                LEFT JOIN #Market gc WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.ID = gc.ID
                INNER JOIN list.Type gt WITH(NOLOCK) ON g2.TypeId = gt.TypeID
            WHERE  
                gt.MarketCount IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY g2.GameID, g2.[Name] 
        ORDER BY g2.[Name
    ) select t1.* from t1 left join mappingt t2 on t1.id=t2.id
      where t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is quite incorrect, i didn't find any `g2` alias in your query, so i would do :

```
WITH t AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT g2.ID, g2.[Name]
     FROM cte c INNER JOIN 
          #Market gc WITH(NOLOCK) 
          ON c.ID = gc.ID INNER JOIN 
          list.Type gt WITH(NOLOCK) 
          ON g2.TypeId = gt.TypeID
    WHERE gt.MarketCount IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT t.*
FROM t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mappingt M WHERE m.id = t.id);
```

I would recommend to visit the [Aaron blog](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) before using `NOLOCK` hint.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mentioning a stored procedure you can map the result of that sproc to a table. Then use a standard left join to filter the results

```
declare @temptable table (id int, name varchar(255))
insert into @temptable exec storedProcname 

select * 
    from @temptable t
    left join Mapping m on m.Id = t.Id
    where m.id is null
```